# Beta testing: App not appearing in Play Store Beta tab

Tags: android, beta-testing

I have been trying for several weeks now to get the Google Alpha / Beta testing functionality on the Play Store to work with no success. As far as I can tell I have followed the process but clearly something is not working from my side. I hope someone on SO can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I have created both an Apha and Beta testing community.

I have added the Beta testing community to the Beta testing section that relates to using Google+ communities to test. My Beta testing community does have members added.

Although I have an Alpha testing community, none of the Alpha testing methods are currently enabled.

On my test device, using a Google account that is a member of my Beta testing community, I only ever see the version of my app that is currently in Prod. I have spent days waiting just in case it takes a couple of days to show up (at least a week which I assume should be long enough).

I need to test the release version because I am trying to test some inapp billing functionality that I had to change due to security warnings from Google relating to my current Prod version.

BUT: if I load the release version of the app directly (instead of downloading from the Play Store) I can see that it is seeing this account as a "test account" because when I test the inapp billing I get the correct message telling me that the subscription will renew every day but I won't be charged. However the Beta version of the app never appears in the "BETA" tab in the Play Store.

I have noticed something "strange" (possibly) in the developer console though: When I click on the "Beta Testing" tab it shows 10399 supported devices and 0 excluded devices for the Beta app. However if I click on the line of the Beta app where you can promote the app etc, the details that are then displayed indicate 0 supported Android devices. Why would this be? This seems to be conflicting information on the console.

Note: The current Prod version of my app was developed using Eclipse. I have recently converted to Android Studio and this is my first upload using Android Studio.

Where else should I be looking to get my app to appear in the Play Store

Thanks

Comment: Did you upload your APK? And if yes, is it published?

Comment: Yes I have - It displays "Uploaded on Aug 1"; Status is "In Beta" and under actions it displays "Promote to Prod".

Comment: Share a link so I can try and install it

Comment: The app is "Telsort" in the Play Store. If you join the "Telsort Beta Testing" community you should receive an update of the beta version. The link to become a tester is [link](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.telsortuk.telsort)

Comment: Your link is wrong: "App not available for this account

Your account isn't currently eligible for this app's testing program." Make it Open Beta it might solve your problem or at least I would be able to download it.

Comment: I've changed it to Open Beta. Thanks

Comment: @Edgehog - I  think the message you are getting is due to delays on Google's side. Did you join the community first? Based on my experience over the past few weeks you should at least get to see the Prod version of the app.

Comment: I'm confused. I was able to download it. And it crashed with: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.telsortuk.telsort.MainActivity.onCreate. Close your question. Beta thing is working. What is not working is your app. Fix it.

Comment: Thanks - it looks like the Open Beta is working in that I can see the app in the Beta tab of a test device. But there seems to be a closed beta testing problem. Part one of my problem is solved in that at least I can see the app in the Beta tab. Thanks. However I'm not seeing the Beta version even though its been up since 1 August. I suspect there are still "supported device" issues which I referred to earlier. I'd really appreciate it if you could drop me an email with your crash details via the developer email on the Play Store. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: "I can see the app in the Beta tab. Thanks. However I'm not seeing the Beta version" which one is it?

Comment: The app appears in the beta tab. But when you click on it you see the Prod version (v1.17) loaded in January 2016. The version uploaded to Beta is v1.19. It is not clear to me whether I should be able to download the beta version directly or whether I must download the Prod version and wait for an update. Bottom line is that I have never been able to see v1.19 in the Play Store (i.e. when click on "Read More" on the app page in the Play Store).

Comment: That is the story for another question. Make a question "I cannot see the updated version number in Beta Google Play" and I am sure you will find the help.

Comment: it is the year 2020, and I can confirm it *still* takes 30 minutes for the opt-in link to become active !

Answer (score 60):

I was just setting up the Beta testing release for the first time and couldn't make the app visible in Play Store. Found the reason in [Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213):

> After publishing an alpha/beta app for the first time, it may take a few hours for your test link to be available to testers. If you publish additional changes, they may take several hours to be available for testers.

After about **35 minutes** the app was published.

As this might not be the issue mentioned in original question, it might help someone.

Comment: looks like this is applicable in my case. My testing link points to the previous version which was supposed to be deactivated and current was supposed to be available. Need to wait an hour or so I believe.

Comment: I had to wait about 25 minutes as well for the link to show. Thanks!

Comment: I have been waiting for 3 days and still the Invitation Link doesn't appear. Message continues to say "This link will appear when you publish your app"

Comment: I have been waiting 3 days and I cannot update to the beta version of the app. It just doesn't appear.

Answer (score 28):

In my case I had published the Beta version and had created the testers but not linked them together. What I had to do was:

1. Go to manage releases
2. Choose a testing method - Closed Beta Testing
3. Then when testers list shows, make active the group of testers you would like to test the app.
4. Save
5. Get Opt-in URL link and paste it in a new tab (you should be logged in to google)
6. Then click at the "Become a Tester" button

You should now be a tester and ready to go.

**@Important** If you still can not find the app by searching in Play Store just copy the "Opt-in URL" into your tester phone's browser and you should see the app.

Hope it helps

Comment: But Opt-in URL wont be there if the application is not yet publish. In my case it is the 1st app. So the url is not been generated

Answer (score 6):

What solved this problem for me was clearing my Play Store app data.

In my case, I had already been on the testers list for days, already accepted the invitation link, and already gotten testing working on other devices. But, the Play Store still wouldn't show the beta version of the app on this particular device.

I went to "App info" for the Google Play Store app, "Memory", then "Clear data". Then I re-opened and was able to see the beta test app.

**Disclaimer:** Use with caution. Clearing your app data may remove some important information. I haven't personally experienced any problems with it, but that doesn't mean you won't.

[image: memory]
[image: clear data]

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion from @Edgehog to use Open Testing solved my problem regarding being able to see my app in the Beta tab of the Play Store.

I have not found a reason yet why the closed beta testing (using emails or groups/communities) would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54213279/9007125)

> - browser cache
> - an actual **active** "testing track"

Answer (score 1):

We are having the same problem in my company. Currently we are investigating possibility that maybe first install on beta channel installs prod version and updates to beta channel version when first app update is released on beta channel. It is weird workflow but the comment on Play Store "Future updates will include beta versions" supports this

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons why this *might* happen but admittedly we did not 100% confirm this.

1) One reason is that you are viewing Google Play under another account that is not on the beta tester list.

2) The other might be an issue (or feature) with the release management. Added a user to an existing closed beta release list.  Changing a list does not activate or force a Save for the "Managed testers" section.  After we edited another field (e.g. feedback channel) then the Save button became active and we clicked save.  This might only then propagate changes. We cannot 100% confirm this was the issue we were facing but our experience points to this.