# Google Play Games Services testing - OAuth failing?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-play-games

Trying to follow instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#step_3_generate_an_oauth_20_client_id

There is a long description of how to generate fingerprints, but this never happened for me... it just said

'Successfully linked your Client ID'

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com

'You only need to include the application ID (1098532227899) in your Android app. '

I did that, I'm testing and I can't connect.  Do I have to get it as an alpha release through the store to test?  I'm listed as a tester, but when I send the invitation I get

'App not available for this account'

If I send myself a signed release APK is that the same as getting it through the store?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [blog](https://www.testingcatalog.com/blog/post/2), there are certain reasons why you encounter the `App not available for this account` error. It might be:

- **Country restriction.** The developer can specify application availability for each country and if on the Google Play you will see a clear message about that - on this page, it will look like “App not available for this account”. The best thing which you can do in this case is to ask developers to the associated Google+ community to add your country to the list.
- **Testers limit.** The developer can also specify a maximum amount of beta testers which means that if this limit is 1000 testers, you won’t be able to get an access to this page. I will look like “App not available for this account” either. You can try to contact developers in this case too.
- **Time delay.** Sometimes, even if you joined Google+ community you will see “App not available for this account” just because it may take up to 4 hours (according to the google documentation) before an application will become available for your account. In this case, I would suggest checking this OPT-IN url after some time, according to my experience it usually takes less than 15 minutes.

You may check this SO post for reference: [Beta testing: App not appearing in Play Store Beta tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063616/beta-testing-app-not-appearing-in-play-store-beta-tab)