# The item you requested is not available for purchase while trying test in app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I did all of these steps but still getting the error, Im in very desperate situation and need help.

1. The status of the app is published
2. I am a tester
   [image]
3. The app is released with closed beta testing method and checked in testers
   [image]
4. App's version code same with the released one
5. Cleared the cache of play store
6. Uninstall - reinstall the google account from the devices (both emulator and phone)
7. Store presence -> In-App products -> Managed Products -> created item is active
8. I also tried everything which mentioned in this link [the item you requested is not available for purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117081/the-item-you-requested-is-not-available-for-purchase)

Comment: check your country as publisher

Comment: refer this link @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063616/beta-testing-app-not-appearing-in-play-store-beta-tab

Comment: 1. You must use signed app (not debug key). 2. Google account on the phone must be the same as developer else go to developer console - options - testers and add new e-mail. Let me know if it's OK now.

Comment: no it's no longer necessary to have a signed app - simply add your test account into the "License Testing" section of your dev console and IAP can be debugged in Android Studio in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

**Have you added your email id in the test purchase account?**

*=> If you launch the first app then you have to follow the following steps.*

**1.** If no then you should first add your email id in the purchase account as a tester. Here I don't know where it is added? Bcz I have no credential.

**2.** After adding an email id in the test purchase account then you have to add your app package name in your google account link and click on become a tester.